# Linux Symbolic link to Mapped Drive

Tags: linux, hyperlink, symlink, shortcut, mapped-drive

I was wonder how I would be able to create a Symbolic link to a directory on a mapped drive?

I have a Mac OS laptop and have a mapped drive pointing to a folder on a remote server which contains a folder called '**content**'.

I am able to access the mapped drive via Terminal and also it the directories without however when I try to create a symbolic link on my laptop ROOT directory pointing to the '**content**' folder on the mapped drive then I get an error.

Here is the command I issue:

```
  ln -s ./site_content /Volumes/***ip-address***/content
```

I then get the following error:

```
  ln: /Volumes/***ip-address***/content/site_content: Input/output error
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Mapped how? nfs? cifs? Sorry, but i don't understand: we are speaking about Linux or OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is backwards. The first path is the target of the link, and the second is where the link is created. If you did not specify where the link is created, it would default to the current directory and the name of the target (e.g. `./content`).

```
 ln -s /Volumes/***ip-address***/content ./site_content
```

You get an error with the previous command because however your drive is mapped, it does not support creating symbolic links on the remote filesystem. What you really wanted was a symbolic link on the local filesystem that references a remote filesystem, which should work fine.